# What is the difference when using KEYS and SCAN in a LUA script?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, lua

I am currently using the **Redis**, version:3.2.12 as a cache memory for my application: Spring Boot. I want to match a list of patterns and then delete them from Redis. I've opted to use LUA scripts and have come up with the following script.

```
local cursor='0';
local keysVar = {};
repeat
 local scanResult = redis.call('SCAN', cursor, 'MATCH', ARGV[1], 'COUNT', 100);
    local keys = scanResult[2];
    for i = 1, #keys do
        keysVar[i] = keys[i];
    end;
    cursor = scanResult[1];
until cursor == '0';
redis.replicate_commands()
redis.call('DEL', unpack(keysVar));
return keysVar ;
```

From what I've read the `SCAN` command was created to break up the blocking `KEYS` command which could present major issues when used in production. But, since I've decided to use LUA and Redis guarantees the script's atomic execution. While executing the script, all server activities are blocked during its entire runtime. Won't using `KEYS` and `SCAN` in an LUA script result in the same as both of them have a time complexity of O(N)?

So, what is the difference between using the above script vs, using

```
return redis.call('DEL', 'defaultKey', unpack(redis.call('KEYS', @keypattern)))
```

One more question. Why is the `KEYS` command regarded as deterministic, can't the number of keys returned change when let's say slave performs the `KEYS` command with a pattern? The reason given for the `SCAN` command to be non-deterministic is that the results returned may vary from master to slave. Can't the same be said for the `KEYS` too?

And since a `SCAN` uses a cursor, how is there a chance of the same key getting returned multiple times?

I am trying to delete a list of patterns using the Redis template.

```
private void clearCache(List<String> patterns) {
        Resource scriptSource = new ClassPathResource("cleanup.lua");
        RedisScript<String> redisScript = RedisScript.of(scriptSource, String.class);
        patterns.forEach(pattern -> {
            redisTemplate.execute(redisScript, Collections.emptyList(), pattern);
        });
    }
```

Is there a correct/recommended way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

> Won't using KEYS and SCAN in an LUA script result in the same as both of them have a time complexity of O(N)?

YES, they both have O(N) complexity. So you should NOT use either in production env.

> So, what is the difference between using the above script vs, using...

The script with an unpacked `keys` result, might fail, if there's too many keys. Because, if I remember correctly, Redis has a limit on the byte-length of a command.

> And since a SCAN uses a cursor, how is there a chance of the same key getting returned multiple times?

Because normally, the keyspace is dynamically during the scan, e.g. new key added, old key expired or removed.

Comment: So, if that's the case, is there any way to delete a key using a pattern without using scan or keys?

Comment: You need to build an index, e.g. set or hash, for those keys that will be deleted, and scan the index to delete them.

Comment: You mean, instead of using a String datatype, I should cache those values in either a set or a hash and then delete them? But isn't the time complexity for a complete iteration O(N) for both sscan and hscan?